# jQuery sortable in nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list with categories and questions (which can both be added dynamically), at the moment I am able to sort the categories using jQuery sortable, but not the questions underneath the categories.

I've tried just adding another .sortable function on the question wrap element but it is not responding at all.

My code at the moment:

```
// HTML template for new fields
const template = `
<div class="row sortwrap">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list catinput" />
    <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
  <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
        <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
  </div>
</div>`;

const vraagTemplate = `
<div class="row" id="question">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="question[]" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>`;
// Count numbers and change accordingly when field is deleted
function updatePlaceholders() {
  // Sortable code
// $('#dynamic_field').sortable( "refresh" );
  let df = $('#dynamic_field');
  df.find('input[name^=cat]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een categorie toe");
  });
  df.find('.sortwrap').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("id", i + 1);
  });
  df.find('.questionlist').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[name^=qu]').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een vraag toe");
    });
  });
}
// Append question template
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.questionbutton', function() {
  let $ql = $(this).closest('.questionlist');
  $ql.append($(vraagTemplate));
  updatePlaceholders();
});

// Delete
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  updatePlaceholders();
});
$('#addcategory').on('click', function() {
let t = $(template)
  $('#dynamic_field').append(t);
  updatePlaceholders();
});

$(function() {
  $('#addcategory').trigger('click');
  $('#question').sortable();
  $('#dynamic_field').sortable({
    cancel: '.questionwrap',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  });

});
```

This is my sortable code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#addcategory').trigger('click');
    $('#question').sortable();
    $('#dynamic_field').sortable({
    cancel: '.questionwrap',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
```

`#question` is the wrap of my question list and `#dynamic_field` is the wrap of my category element (the questions are also inside this element).

How can I make my questions also sortable? And also only make then sortable inside their parent div (so I can't drag a question from one category to the other but only within its own category).

Comment: Remember that Sortable is being initialized when page is ready. It looks like you're adding elements dynamically. You will want to `refresh` when you add elements to either list. Then you will also want to use `items` properly and potentially `handle` for each list set. If you want further help, please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

One of the first thing I have noticed about your code is that the ID is repeated for each creation of a dynamic element. This will cause a lot of issues when you have 6 `#question` elements. This can be addressed by adding the ID to the element when it's created and creating a unique ID. For example, if there are 0 `#questions` then you can count that and add 1.

```
<div id="question-1"></div>
<script>
var id = $("[id|='question']").length + 1;
</script>
```

In this, `id` would be 2. there is one element that contains "question" and the `|=` selector will look for that before the `-` in a ID name. Can also use `^=` selector.

Making use of `handle` will help a lot too. This will help allow proper sorting of nested items versus their parents. Also `containment` is helpful here too unless you want to move them between lists.

Consider the following code. It's a little clunky and I hope you can see what I am referring to.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeSortable(obj, options) {
    console.log("Make Sortable", obj);
    obj.sortable(options);
    obj.disableSelection();
  }

  function updateSort(obj) {
    console.log("Update Sortable", obj);
    obj.sortable("refresh");
  }

  function addQuestion(q, c) {
    console.log("Add Question", q, c);
    var makeSort = $("[id|='question']", c).length === 0;
    var question = $("<div>", {
      class: "question",
      id: "question-" + ($("div[id|='question']", c).length + 1)
    });
    question.append($("<div>", {
      class: "col-md-8"
    }).html(q));
    question.append($("<div>", {
      class: "col-md-4"
    }).html("<button class='btn btn-danger btn-remove'>X</button>"));
    question.appendTo($(".catcontent", c));
    console.log(makeSort, question, c);
    if (makeSort) {
      makeSortable($(".catcontent", c), {
        containment: "parent",
        items: "> div.question"
      });
    } else {
      updateSort($("[id|='question']", c).eq(0).parent());
    }
  }

  function makeCategory(name) {
    console.log("Make Category", name);
    var makeSort = $("[id|='category']").length === 0;
    var cat = $("<div>", {
      class: "category ui-widget",
      id: "category-" + ($("[id|='category']").length + 1)
    });
    cat.append($("<div>", {
      class: "cathead ui-widget-header"
    }).html(name + "<i class='btn btn-add-question'>+</i>"));
    cat.append($("<div>", {
      class: "catcontent ui-widget-content col-md-8"
    }));
    cat.appendTo($("#cat-wrapper"));
    if (makeSort) {
      makeSortable($("#cat-wrapper"), {
        handle: ".cathead",
        items: "> div.category"
      });
    } else {
      updateSort($("#cat-wrapper"));
    }
  }

  $('#addcategory').on('click', function() {
    let t = $(template);
    $('#dynamic_field').append(t);
    updatePlaceholders();
  });

  $(".categorybutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeCategory($(".catinput").val());
    $(".catinput").val("");
  });

  $(".catwrap").on("click", ".btn-add-question", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var resp = prompt("Question to Add:");
    addQuestion(resp, $(this).parent().parent());
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row sortwrap">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    New Category
    <input type="text" class="form-control catinput" placeholder="Category Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-success categorybutton">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="cat-wrapper" class="row catwrap">
</div>
```

Hope that helps.